# Windows form application not closing properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm running a simple .NET Windows Forms application. When I click the close button, the Windows form gets closed, but the process is not closing. When I look at the Task Manager, I see that the process for the application is still live, as a background process. 
[image]

Can somebody explain why that is? Am I missing some function when it's closing?

Comment: Are you sure the main form of the application is closed? Are there multiple forms?

Comment: Does your application start any threads?  If so, do you set their `IsBackground` property to `true`?

Comment: OnFormClosing event put Application.Exit();

Comment: @thewisegod i'm sure main form is closed since application has only one form

Comment: Did you create SmsAlertRemainder as a Notification Application?

Comment: @BlackFrog no but i have used this [metroui](https://github.com/viperneo/winforms-modernui)

Comment: @Gayan : if answer is userful, please accept and mark as answer

Comment: Then you need to verify which Form you are actually closing.  This link to the code doesn't help me. I need to see code of your application.

Comment: Use the debugger to find out what it is doing.  Use Debug > Break All and Debug > Windows > Threads and look at the call stacks of those threads.  You'll surely find a thread back that you used to read the SMS messages.  Set its IsBackground property to *true* to get it to terminate automatically.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks if you put this as answer i can mark it that fixed my problem. problem was i'm connecting to mobile phone but when i close the form GSM connection still there not disposing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
Application.Exit();
```

in your Form's closing event.

Answer (score 0):

[**Application.Exit**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx)

Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed. This is the code to use if you are have called Application.Run (WinForms applications), this method stops all running message loops on all threads and closes all windows of the application.

```
// WinForms app
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
```

Put this code on you from's closing event.

Comment: Someone is downvoting here every answer.

Comment: I didn't down vote, however I would guess someone down-voted because all the answers are telling the question asker to hit his problem with a hammer, instead of finding what is keeping his application open.

Comment: @JoelC i agree with you

Answer (score -3):

The main reason for not close properly, When your application works with the multi threading. You should use the following, it's works for me as well.

```
Application.ExitThread();
```